# Может ли база данных как-то оповещать приложение?

Tags: mysql, sql, база-данных, sql-server, postgresql

Может ли база данных как-то оповестить приложение о том что в одной из её таблиц изменилось значение определенного поля? 
Допустим есть два сервера, один обновляет значения таблиц в базе данных, а второй в зависимости от измененного значения делает какие-то вычисления, при этом сервера между собой не должны взаимодействовать.

Comment: SqlServer [может](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/62xk7953(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: Определитесь с СУБД которую вы используете и отразите это в тегах вопроса. Подобные средства не определяются стандартами SQL и поэтому в разных СУБД могут делаться совершенно разными способами. И в части случаев, даже если явного средства в вашей СУБД нет при большом желании можно что то придумать нестандартное (если СУБД поддерживает хоть какое нибудь  общение с внешним миром)

Comment: PostgreSQL тоже [может](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgresql/9.6/sql-notify).

Comment: каким образом оповестить? какое приложение? добавьте деталей

Comment: пока что напрашивается обыкновенный триггер